# FFMPEG android is processing slow

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java as my framework for FFMPEG

I'm trying to convert an image to a video using this command

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i input.jpg -strict -2 -vcodec mpeg4 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

It took about 32 seconds to finish the process which is very slow for my requirements.

Is there a way to speed this up? I'm thinking of something around 5 seconds, perhaps approximately equal to the specified length of the video

here's the log btw

```
11-23 12:12:13.587 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.lo.and.dev/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
11-23 12:12:13.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
11-23 12:12:13.617 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
11-23 12:12:13.617 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
11-23 12:12:13.617 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
11-23 12:12:13.707 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20151122_172809.jpg':
11-23 12:12:13.707 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 95165 kb/s
11-23 12:12:13.717 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
11-23 12:12:13.727 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: [swscaler @ 0xb5d89000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/out.mp4':
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   Metadata:
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:     Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 ( [0][0][0] / 0x0020), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:     Metadata:
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 mpeg4
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: Stream mapping:
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
11-23 12:12:13.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
11-23 12:12:14.707 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=     343kB time=00:00:00.12 bitrate=23400.5kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:15.247 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=    5 fps=4.2 q=4.9 size=     345kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=14125.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:15.737 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=    7 fps=4.0 q=10.2 size=     347kB time=00:00:00.28 bitrate=10149.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:16.467 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   10 fps=4.1 q=18.9 size=     350kB time=00:00:00.40 bitrate=7167.7kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:17.037 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   12 fps=4.0 q=24.8 size=     352kB time=00:00:00.48 bitrate=6007.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:17.567 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   14 fps=3.9 q=27.8 size=     403kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=5893.7kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:18.337 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   17 fps=4.0 q=31.0 size=     406kB time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=4891.5kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:18.847 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   19 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     408kB time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=4398.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:19.607 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   22 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     411kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate=3827.4kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:20.107 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   24 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     413kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate=3525.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:20.637 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   26 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     460kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=3624.3kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:21.157 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   28 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     462kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=3381.1kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:21.667 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   30 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     464kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=3169.7kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:22.167 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   32 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     466kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=2984.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:22.897 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   35 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:01.40 bitrate=2746.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:23.657 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   38 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     517kB time=00:00:01.52 bitrate=2788.3kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:24.387 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   41 fps=4.0 q=31.0 size=     521kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=2600.1kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:24.887 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   43 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     523kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate=2488.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:25.417 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   45 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     525kB time=00:00:01.80 bitrate=2387.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:25.967 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   47 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     527kB time=00:00:01.88 bitrate=2294.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:26.477 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   49 fps=3.9 q=24.8 size=     572kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=2390.0kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:27.297 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   52 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     577kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate=2271.5kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:27.987 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   55 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     580kB time=00:00:02.20 bitrate=2159.1kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:28.737 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   58 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     583kB time=00:00:02.32 bitrate=2058.2kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:29.247 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   60 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     585kB time=00:00:02.40 bitrate=1996.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:30.017 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   63 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     633kB time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=2057.7kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:30.557 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   65 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     635kB time=00:00:02.60 bitrate=2000.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:31.057 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   67 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     637kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=1947.4kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:31.627 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   69 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     639kB time=00:00:02.76 bitrate=1897.0kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:32.167 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   71 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     641kB time=00:00:02.84 bitrate=1849.5kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:32.927 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   74 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     689kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=1907.2kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:33.407 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   76 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     691kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=1862.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:34.157 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   79 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     694kB time=00:00:03.16 bitrate=1800.0kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:34.657 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   81 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     696kB time=00:00:03.24 bitrate=1760.7kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:35.217 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   83 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     698kB time=00:00:03.32 bitrate=1723.3kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:35.777 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   85 fps=3.9 q=24.8 size=     744kB time=00:00:03.40 bitrate=1791.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:36.297 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   87 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     747kB time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=1759.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:36.827 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   89 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     750kB time=00:00:03.56 bitrate=1724.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:37.547 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   92 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     753kB time=00:00:03.68 bitrate=1675.4kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:38.297 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   95 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     756kB time=00:00:03.80 bitrate=1629.1kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:38.797 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=   97 fps=3.9 q=24.8 size=     801kB time=00:00:03.88 bitrate=1690.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:39.547 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  100 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     806kB time=00:00:04.00 bitrate=1650.2kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:40.047 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  102 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     808kB time=00:00:04.08 bitrate=1621.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:40.807 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  105 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     811kB time=00:00:04.20 bitrate=1581.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:41.267 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  107 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     813kB time=00:00:04.28 bitrate=1555.9kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:42.057 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  110 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     861kB time=00:00:04.40 bitrate=1602.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:42.557 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  112 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     863kB time=00:00:04.48 bitrate=1578.1kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:43.307 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  115 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     866kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate=1542.4kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:43.817 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  117 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     868kB time=00:00:04.68 bitrate=1519.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:44.517 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  120 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     871kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate=1486.8kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:45.277 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  123 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     919kB time=00:00:04.92 bitrate=1530.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:45.987 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  125 fps=3.9 q=31.0 size=     921kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=1509.4kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:45.987 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: frame=  125 fps=3.9 q=31.0 Lsize=     923kB time=00:00:05.00 bitrate=1511.6kbits/s    
11-23 12:12:45.987 4228-4228/com.lo.and.dev W/com.lo.and.util: video:921kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.148301%
```

Comment: You're using the software scaler. Last time I used ffmpeg in android a few years ago, hardware acceleration was NOT supported. The VLC developers did some work in this area if I'm not mistaken. ffmpeg in android may have hardware support by now

Comment: sorry I'm quite new with ffmpeg, how can I use the hardware acceleration for ffmpeg? is it only the manifest? or do I need to configure something else?

Comment: Looking at the output more carefully, "[swscaler @ 0xb5d89000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly"... it looks like "pix_fmt" flag is wrong. Trying omitting that and see what happens

Comment: tried it, the process is still slow and the message is still there

Comment: Consider switching to a native (Java) solution using [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Comment: @AlexCohn hi, do you know any good tutorial for MediaCodec, I'm going try it but don't know where to start. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i input.jpg -strict -2 -vcodec mpeg4 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast out.mp4'`

More descriptions you can find here [H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264)

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's better if you can include a little explanation for how it addresses the issue, to help others to learn what the various options you've specified are and how they work.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer. Under the link you can find a more detailed description for ffmpeg commands